# Is there a colour picker that works with Wayland or XWayland?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, colors

I tried gpick, gcolor2, gcolor3, [pick](https://github.com/stuartlangridge/ColourPicker), [pychrom](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/pychrom/) and none of them seem to work with Wayland. I am running Arch Linux 64-bit with GNOME 3.22.1 through XWayland (default since 3.22.x). I don't want to change into an X session just to pick a colour.

Anyone had success with this?

Comment: None that I know of... afaik the dbus api that should allow apps to access those resources is not implemented yet.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: i also stuck on X11 with gcolor2. seems that gcolor3 is on the way but i dont expect it too fast

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible with wayland, because wayland applications don't have access to the surfaces of other apps.

Answer (score 18):

[grim](https://github.com/emersion/grim) is a screenshot tool for Wayland that is able to do that:

```
grim -g "$(slurp -p)" -t ppm - | convert - -format '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' txt:-
```

After selecting a point on the screen with the mouse, it produces output like this:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (40,85,119)  #285577  srgb(40,85,119)
```

Comment: Note that grim uses the wlr-screencopy protocol and slurp uses wlr-layer-shell. These should be supported by wlroots-based compositors, but probably not any others.

Comment: I've added the following line to my Sway config. It lets me select a pixel on the screen and puts its color as a hex value on the system clipboard: `bindsym $mod+Shift+p exec grim -g "$(slurp -p)" -t ppm - | convert - -format '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' txt:- | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | wl-copy`

Comment: I get `slurp: invalid option -- 'p'`.  The man page for slurp doesn't list `p`.

Comment: grim does not work with GNOME accroding to: https://github.com/emersion/grim/issues/58

Comment: slurp doesn't work on my wayland with gnome in terminal: `compositor doesn't support zwlr_layer_shell_v1`

Comment: @MatthiasBraun, please try `bindsym $mod+Shift+p exec slurp -p | grim -g - - | convert - txt: | awk 'NR==2 { print $3 }' | wl-copy` from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/t8k07z/comment/hzylyb7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: In sway, this does not work while the [inactive windows transparency script](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/blob/master/contrib/inactive-windows-transparency.py) is running

Answer (score 12):

For gnome/wayalnd you can use the dbus api:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Screenshot --method org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot.PickColor
```

Comment: This worked for me on gnome Wayland. But you have to multiply the output numbers by 255 if you need RGB.

Comment: This color picker worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Finally something that works for Ubuntu. I wrote a simple bash script to convert gdbus float output to RGB and HEX in a nicer output (BSD-3 license, enjoy): https://gist.github.com/byrro/7a74e54f63667bbb066fa309208a6cba

Answer (score 4):

Expanding upon [@sigmasd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665604/66118)'s answer, I have this BASH script called `colorpicker` that has a GUI picker and it works for Wayland / Ubuntu 22.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the gdbus output
output=$(gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot --object-path /org/gnome/Shell/Screenshot --method org.gnome.Shell.Screenshot.PickColor)
colors=($(echo $output | command grep -o "[0-9\.]*"))

# Convert to 255-based RGB format
for ((i = 0; i < ${#colors[@]}; i++)); do
    colors[$i]=$(printf '%.0f' $(echo "${colors[$i]} * 255" | bc))
done

echo   "RGB: ${colors[0]} ${colors[1]} ${colors[2]}"
printf "HEX: #%02x%02x%02x\n" "${colors[0]}" "${colors[1]}" "${colors[2]}"
```

Example usage:

```
./colorpicker
RGB: 255 255 255
HEX: #ffffff
```

Comment: Love this! For those who haven't tried this out, it produces a cursor featuring a color magnifier. Once you click with the cursor, the output is printed in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

No, security requires only a trusted app to be permitted access to the output of other apps.

"In GNOME, you can use Screenshot tool (available in overview or as Printscreen hotkey or as gnome-screenshot command) to capture a screenshot of the full desktop or a particular window."

Then use gimp/krita/etc to get the color off the image.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Screen_capture_is_not_available_with_usual_apps

Comment: [KolourPaint](https://kde.org/applications/graphics/kolourpaint/) serves that purpose too. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioViniciusMenezesMedei KolourPaint captures a black screenshot on my Debian 10 (Buster) running Wayland. I believe there has been some changes in the new Wayland version as I wasnt facing issues of black screen in Debian 9 (I was using a simple but cool app [Picker](https://kryogenix.org/code/pick/) previously, which is no longer working).

Comment: Gnome can publish a color picker(trusted) like screenshot tool

Answer (score 3):

There is azote wallpaper manager for wayland and it has a built in color picker
https://github.com/nwg-piotr/azote

Also you can use:

```
grim -g "$(slurp -p)" -t ppm - | convert - -format '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' txt:-
```

or if you are using sway wm:

```
swaynag -t warning -m "$(grim -g "$(slurp -p)" -t ppm - | convert - -format '%[pixel:p{0,0}]' txt:-)"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using wayfire on ArchLinuxARM and was also looking into this.

Based on the solutions provided here I put up a script to make it easy. The script uses grim, slurp and convert as suggested above and also uses zenity to generate a nice color selector dialog to tweak the selected color if necessary. Once the "Select" button of the dialog is clicked it uses wl-copy to store it on the clipboard. The provided Makefile installs .desktop and icon files for easy application menu access. Hope this is of any use:

Repository: https://github.com/jgmdev/wl-color-picker

AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wl-color-picker/

Comment: Using https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/zenity to display the color dialog is clever.  I'm using this to pick colors now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just recently stumbled over this:
https://github.com/hyprwm/hyprpicker

This is a wl-roots based color picker and therefore a native wayland application. Once started it freezes your screen and gives you a cursor with a kind of magnification area to select a pixel. When clicked the screen returns to normal and the color is show in the terminal (an auto-copy option, which writes the value to the clipboard is available too, but this could be done via piping into wl-clipboard too and there currently is a bug in this feature which stops hyprpicker to work after a number of runs).

This is quite nice and seems to work reasonably well, but I personally prefer the grim/slurp/convert solution mentioned here since I have those tools installed already.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`yad` dialog](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/):

```
yad --color
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Can you confirm/point to the relevant documentation that states the compatibility with (X)Wayland, as required by the OP?

Comment: This just brings up a colour dialog. I think the OP is looking for an app where you can click somewhere on the screen and find out what colour that pixel is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gnome Shell Extension **Color Picker** that works fine for me:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3396/color-picker/

It is also really easy to install.